# trouble exporting correctly to unity

Tags: export

so i'm currently working with

- unity 2018.2.21f1
- vuforia
- blender 2.80

and im finding it impossible to export this file to unity (*linked at the bottom*)

the animation doesn't export properly, neither does the textures its just a mess

any ideas or help where i've gone wrong?

[Download Blend File Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13SrEXyfPQjzE0882S97tIdNpciLZ8W9h)

greatly appreciate any feedback and help!

Comment: What export format are you using?

Comment: (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  this is the blender stack exchange link to load .blend files is very comfortable because it links your file to the question